# Load data fixtures in setUpBeforeClass with LiipFunctionalTestBundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, phpunit, liipfunctionaltestbundle

As the title says, I'd like to know how to load the data fixtures in the method `setUpBeforeClass`.  The test class extends `Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\Test\WebTestCase`.

At the moment I have this:

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->client = $this->createClient();
    $this->fixtures = $this->loadFixtures([
        'App\DataFixtures\MyFixtures',
        // more fixtures
    ])->getReferenceRepository();
}
```

However the tests seem to take too long and there is really no need for the fixtures to be loaded before each test.

When I tried to load the fixtures in `setUpBeforeClass` I've got an error:

> Error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/cezar/phpprojects/livegene/vendor/liip/functional-test-bundle/src/Test/WebTestCase.php:252

A look into the source code of *LiipFunctionalTestBundle* revealed this snippet:

```
protected function loadFixtures(array $classNames = [], bool $append = false, ?string $omName = null, string $registryName = 'doctrine', ?int $purgeMode = null): ?AbstractExecutor
{
    $container = $this->getContainer();

    $dbToolCollection = $container->get('liip_functional_test.services.database_tool_collection');
    $dbTool = $dbToolCollection->get($omName, $registryName, $purgeMode, $this);
    $dbTool->setExcludedDoctrineTables($this->excludedDoctrineTables);

    return $dbTool->loadFixtures($classNames, $append);
}
```

Is it possible to do this, what I wish, and if yes, how could it be achieved?

Comment: Do you need anything beside the database in your tests, e.g. stuff from the container or sending web requests? If not, you could use the DoctrineTestHelpers to create a database connection for an in memory-sqlite-db and populate that. That should work with a static context as well

Comment: No, I don't need anything special. I use `sqlite3` for testing, too.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is a working EntityManager with a (partially) valid database schema to query against, you can use the DoctrineTestHelper provided by the Symfony DoctrineBridge:

```
public static function setUpBeforeClass()
{
    $config = DoctrineTestHelper::createTestConfiguration();
    $config->setNamingStrategy(new UnderscoreNamingStrategy());
    $entityManager = DoctrineTestHelper::createTestEntityManager($config);
    $schemaTool = new SchemaTool($entityManager);
    $schemaTool->createSchema([
        // List of entities to create schema for
        $entityManager->getClassMetadata(User::class),
        $entityManager->getClassMetadata(Task::class),
    ]);
    static::$entityManager = $entityManager;
}
```

By default this will use SQLite3 in memory for the connection, but you could also point it to any other database using the config and the appropriate drivers.
Be careful to also register any custom DBAL types and  LifecycleEvent-listeners you have, as this will change how the data is processed and whether mapping to your entities works.

Now in your tests you can use `static::$entityManager` as always with the tables or insert test fixtures as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't know about the `DoctrineTestHelper`.